# c# wpf linq items quantity in carts shown in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have a WPF application with a database made using Entity Framework code first.

I have two classes

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IList<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `datagrid` bound to a linq query that can get all my items and I set the result as source of this datagrid.

```
 var items = (from item in db.Items 
              select item).ToList();
 mydatagrid.ItemsSource = items;
```

My main problem :

- How can I calculate how many times an item has been inserted in a cart?

And then, I have to insert the result in a column of my datagrid, so my result should be able to be bound to a column.

Comment: *how many times an item has been inserted in a cart* What do you mean? Why doesn't `Cart.Items.Count()` give you what you want? Or do you mean the number of times one individual item has been added?

Comment: @GertArnold second you said. number of times one item has been added. I have a many to many relationship here, and for this I have a link table CartItem that stores both Id of cart and item.

Answer (score 1):

You don't add items multiple times to a many-to-many association. You have to store the number of items in the junction table. To make that possible, you should make the junction part of your class model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
}

public class CartItem
{
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public int NrOfItems { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can get the numbers of items and the items themselves from `Cart.CartItems`, basically like so:

```
from c in Carts
from ci in c.CartItems
select new { ci.Item.Name, ci.NrOfItems }
```

Comment: is CartItem class mapped automatically as link table from code first? do I have to set manually primary keys and foreign keys?

Comment: This will automatically create the foreign keys in the database (by convention). You'll have to map the composite primary key (CartId, ItemId) yourself.

Comment: this method would mess up a lot of things in my application. Does exist another method?

Comment: Well, you apparently had a `CartItem` table with non-unique `CartId, ItemId` combinations. That defeats the purpose of a relational database and in the end will make it much harder to do things right. Bite the bullet and put things straight now.